# Solve for x, permutation multiplication

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations

Could anyone help me out with this? I'm supposed to solve the equation for $x$.
$$(1 3 4)x(32)=(1 2 3 4) \textrm{ in } S_4$$

Comment: Wow, this is really clear! What's "permutation multiplication"? What's "$(b)$"? What's that "$iS_4$" at the end?

Comment: Ok, sorry.. The (b) shows that it is task B, so dont mind that. the "i S4" thing at the end tells that is is supposed to be in the symmetrical group of the power 3

Answer (score 2):

*Hint:* "Multiply" (= compose) the equation on the right by the inverse of $(3\,2)$ and on the left by the inverse of $(1\,3\,4)$.

Answer (score 0):

You have $(134)x(32)=(1234)$

$(134)^{-1}(134)x(32)(32)^{-1}=(134)^{-1}(1234)(32)^{-1}$

but
given that the order of $(134)$ is $3$ and of $(32)$ is $2$ we have that

$(134)^{-1}=(134)^{2}=(143)$ and $(32)^{-1}=(32)$

so we have

$x=(143)(1234)(32)=(231)$